# Writing test case in negative method using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

Hi actually I'm begginer in writing test cases using mockito, can anyone help me in writing test case for below program using mockito in negative scenario. Sample code of mine looks like below

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity() ;
entity. setId("1234") ;
entity. setName("Sam" ) ;
myRepository. save(entity) ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with negative? Repo can't save? If you can give us more context it will be easier to help you

Comment: yes repo can't save or should throw an exception while saving

Comment: i'm saying in failed case

Comment: please, describe the case in all details: if any entity is being provided to the repositories `save` method, then exception is thrown? or is it being happened under some special circumstances?

Comment: a test should be written after method's specification was described correctly, we just do not know what we are testing as well as which environment should be provided before invoking the method

Comment: if you are testing the repo you don't need mockito in this case. You need to catch the error and verify if it is what you expect

Comment: I had just mentioned sample code, My code looks like below.@service public class MyService{  public void saveSomethind() { above code... } }

Comment: Actually I'm testing service method where I'm calling repo

Comment: If you post the error you are throwing when Save fail I can put together an answer

Comment: For positive scenario I have written as      Mockito. when(repo. save(entiry) ). thenReturn(entity) ; it worked fine but for negative I don't have any idea how to write

Comment: Even for that mockito doeasn't make sense. You use mockito when you are testing sunctionality of a class and the repository(for instance) is a dependency. In the example you provided the only logic is the repository so you are testing that. If you mock it basically you are not testing it

Comment: As @rick mentions, you should describe what you actually try to test, and what you expect to happen. Unit tests are for testing units of code, and right now, you have no code to handle the exception, so you can't write a test for that either. You could explicitly throw an exception from your mock (using `when(..).thenThrow(..)`, but with your current code, that would just throw the exception within your method and within your test as well, and it wouldn't make a lot of sense to write a test for that.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading a good Mockito tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your case, but if your "myRepository" is a mock you could force it to throw an exception during save.

Examples: [Mockito exceptions](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-exceptions)

Example: `when(myRepository.save(any())).thenThrow(Exception.class);`

Comment: this would imply a that you are catching the error in the calling class to do something. The example is not like that

Comment: I don't agree as the purpose of JUnit test is also to detect changes. Such test will detect if someone add exception handling in caller class, which may be really useful.

Comment: as you said you are testing error management in caller class. In the example provided there is none of it

Comment: Indeed, but I thought it may be consider as a "negative" scenario.

Comment: Thank you but small doubt when I run coverage As then every line showing in green expect                       when(myRepository.save(any())).thenThrow(Exception.class); for this line it is red. So it is not covering?

Comment: It must be something else, as this is just simple statement.